# How to get the number of elements

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I'm developing an application in C++ and I need to know the number of elements of a variable. I'm looking for how to do this but I'm not able to find a solution for this. The variable is defined in this way:

```
unsigned char *values = (unsigned char *) some_function(some_parameter);
// "some_function" takes "some_parameter" and fills "values" correctly
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Best regards.

Comment: Completely depends on the definition of `some_function`... It seems to return a pointer which points to some memory which was allocated somewhere... Probably in the function.

Comment: What do you mean by "number of elements of a variable"?

Comment: The size in bytes of the variable.

Comment: `sizeof(some_parameter)` but note that if some_parameter is a pointer it will tell you the size of the pointer, not the size of what it is pointing to.

Comment: I guess you mean the number of elements of a dynamically allocated array (or even worse: `malloc`)

Comment: That just gives me the size of the data type, in this case 8 bytes.

Comment: @Víctor Can you please tell us what the function is?

Comment: @Víctor Exactly, there is no way to do what you want. A pointer is a pointer, it doesn't have a size. Time to learn how to use `std::vector` which does do what you want.

Comment: I'm not the one who implements "some_function". This function is provided by a library.

Comment: It's to be feared that it's a C function returning malloc'ed memory. I further fear that he can't change the definition of the function, leading to no option to determine the size of the allocated memory (unless constant and documented or similar). Maybe, as PP. shows in his answer, the length can be found out using the content, i.e. some termination character or "protocol"

Comment: Or maybe the library has `some_function_get_size(some_parameter)`.

Comment: Or maybe the library has `some_function_will_return_this_size_if_given_this_parameter(some_parameter)` or a similar thing in human language to be found in some documentation if he's lucky.

Comment: There is no way I can find the size by myself? The library doesn't seems to provide a way to get the size of that.

Comment: I'm using the FreeImage library. "some_function()" is "FreeImage_GetBits()".

Comment: In this case you can determine the size of the "bit data" of an image by querying the width and height (GetPitch, GetHeight) as well as the number of bits per pixel (GetBBP). Note I wrote "GetPitch", not "GetWidth", as one line can be larger than the number of pixels (it's rounded up to align the memory)

Comment: Just multiplying these three pieces of information? There is no more information I have to consider to get the exact size in bytes of "values"?

Comment: Voting to close because the author failed to read the function documentation.

Comment: @PP. To admit, the documentation should had mentioned how this data is laid out (and thus how large it is). I'm sure it's stated *somewhere*, but the function `GetBits` should point the reader to this description (which I failed to find).

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you told us which function you're using ([FreeImage::GetBits](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/fnet/html/F6129E99.htm)), we now know that you're querying the raw data of an image. Its size is the product of the pitch and height of the image, as seen in this formula:

```
int size = image.GetPitch() * image.GetHeight();
```

This is the size in *bytes*, which is the number of elements if you access a `char` pointer. But speaking of "number of elements" in such a case (where we speak of some low-level memory, a bit stream with no high-level types) is a bit misleading, as when reading the question one might think it's about a higher level *array*.

In case you wonder: Raw image data is typically laid out in rows of size `pitch`, one pixel after another, from left to right, where the size per pixel can depend on some storage format (for example 1 byte grayscale, 3 bytes RGB with 8 bit per channel, 1 bit for monochrome bitmaps, and many more formats).

These rows are laid out from top to bottom (in most cases) or sometimes from bottom to top (in the case of BMP file format for example). The `pitch` is at least the `width` of the image times the size per pixel, so all pixels have space in such a "scan line", which is how such a memory per line of the image is called. It's rounded up to some alignment, so every line can start at an aligned address in the memory for the whole image. The unused space is called "padding" and ignored.

*Depending on the library*, sometimes "pitch" means "pixels per line" in the memory, not "bytes per line", but in this case it's already given in *bytes* so you only have to multiply by the image height. Note that typically the height is *not* padded like the width, since there's no advantage of doing so.

Comment: In the documentation they state this? I don't see your formula anywhere. How you determined that?

Comment: I made a mistake, please see my edit. I'm not 100% sure about this formula, but (1) it's a common way to lay out images in memory and (2) they include an example at the documentation of `GetBits` in the PDF documentation where they access the pixels. There, they increase the raw byte pointer by the pitch per line they're stepping through.

Comment: Thank you man. I see it now. But, according to that, the "pitch" multiplied by the "height" will give the number of bits or the number of bytes?

Comment: Number of bytes, as the "pitch" is (in this library) defined as "the width of the bitmap in **bytes**"

Comment: Thank you very much man, really. Thanks for all the patience and kindness. Huge hugs!

Comment: Remember to check the pointer for being `NULL`, since the doc also says it can be `NULL` in some cases, where there is no image data.

Comment: Yes! In the documentation they provide a method named FreeImage_HasPixels(). It's exactly the same to use this method or compare the pointer to NULL, right?

Comment: I'm afraid, don't know this, but it's **never** a bad idea to check for pointers against null (if you're not 100% sure) before dereferencing them, so I'd check it here independently of some other function! You never know if there are other cases in which a null pointer is returned...

Answer (score 2):

You can never deterministically know the length of an array given a pointer to the beginning of the array. You must pass some information along with the array.

That extra information may be in the form of:

- another return value specifying the length
- an agreed encoding that encodes the length into the beginning of the array
- an agreed encoding that marks the end of the array (e.g. `\0` at the end of a string)

Comment: I'm not the one who implements "some_function". This function is provided by a library.

Comment: Then point us to the library, please. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: The library should tell you how to obtain the length, unless you are passing in the length as a parameter, in which case you already know it.

Comment: I'm using the FreeImage library. "some_function()" is "FreeImage_GetBits()".

Comment: Let me check man. I'll tell you in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @PP. I'm almost sure you should access the pixels using `y * pitch + x`. I didn't read the documentation however, but this is what "pitch" is for.

Comment: @PP. Also, I'm almost sure that the cast to `FIRGBF*` should only be done if it's `type == FIT_RGBF`, as I just saw an example code where they check this first. It also makes sense, since depending on the storage format you can't access the data simply by casting it to the same type independent of the format (i.e. bits per pixel).

Comment: @leemes the formula your provide works for every image type and color depth?

Comment: Yes it works for every color depth (that's what makes the difference between talking about pixels and bytes). Note that I made a mistake since "pitch" is given in bytes, not pixels, please see my edit. This also counts for my previous comments to this answer: `y * pitch + x` is thus **also wrong**; the real formula for accessing pixels in the bit data is a bit more complicated. See the PDF documentation of the function `GetBits()`, there they show an example. They process it row by row, increasing the "raw" pointer by `pitch` **bytes** (not pixels!) after reading each row.

Comment: `BYTE *data = image.GetBits(); BYTE *rowData = (data + y * image.GetPitch());` Then depending on the pixel format: `FIRGBF rgbPixel = ((FIRGBF*)rowData)[x];` for RGBF format, `BYTE bytePixel = rowData[x]` for 8bbp format (grayscale or 256 indexed colors), and other formats are even trickier.